# What is going on grammatically in the opening line of One Hundred Years of Solitude?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, infinitives

The opening line of One Hundred Years of Solitude in the English translation reads:

> Many years later, as he **faced** the firing squad, Colonel Aureliano Buendía **was to remember** that distant afternoon when his father **took him to discover** ice.

I have emboldened the verbs here. I am trying to understand the grammatical structure of the phrase "was to remember".

My understanding, for reference, is that "I ate cake" is the "past tense",  "I was eating cake" is the "past progressive", and "I had eaten cake" is a kind of "compound past tense". (I have no knowledge of formal grammar so I'm putting things in quotation marks because I'm not sure the terms are well-defined). What sort of "compound tense" is **was to remember**?

As a native English speaker, the meaning of the phrase is clear to me. There are three relevant times in this sentence: the time A when Aureliano Buendía discovered ice, the time B when he faced the firing squad, and the time C when I am reading the sentence. A comes before B, and B in turn comes before C.

Because A and B come before C, the sentence is in the past tense. The verb **faced** is in the simple past because it references an event that took place at time B from the perspective of the current time C. Similarly, "took him to discover" is in the simple past because it refers to an event that took place at time A from the perspective of the current time C. The "was to remember" is different: it refers to an event taking place at time A from the perspective of the later time B, both times being before the present time C. So it seems like a "past within a past" construction.

---

I've been trying to think of examples of using "was to [infinitive]", but all the examples I can think of involve an additional participle in between the was and the infinitive:

> I was *supposed* to buy groceries, but I forgot.
>
> He was *trying* to call me.

Comment: "Was to remember that distant afternoon" is the same as if it said, "remembered that distant afternoon..."

Comment: I can't think of a better way to translate "había de recordar".

Comment: I don't want to create another answer, but "was to remember" has a sense of predestination, as if to say "it was his destiny to remember".  I could say, for example:  "On his 21st birthday, he was to learn the dangers of excess."

Comment: Does *había* there mean "was obliged to, had to, was destined to" as @Epanoui suggested in the comment above with respect to English **was to**?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The verb *be* followed by a to-infinitive is used in historical narratives to convey that something took place later than the narrative moment. In your example,

> Many years later, as he faced the firing squad, Colonel Aureliano Buendía **was to remember** that distant afternoon when his father took him to discover ice.

the translator uses this construction to establish two historical times: the narrative moment “when his father took him to discover ice” and a later time “when [he] was to remember”. It is important that he establishes the narrative moment, because proper understanding of the next clause

> At that time Macondo was a village of twenty adobe houses

requires the reader to know that the narrative moment has already been established, meaning the text is describing the Macondo of Buendía’s childhood, not of his later life.

Other examples:

> Here he **was to remain** until he died. (Earnest Brehaut, “[Introduction](https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/basis/gregory-hist.asp)” from his translation of Gregory of Tours’ *History of the Franks*) *[he remained there after the narrative moment, when he was shut in to a cell]*
>
> This **was to be** an eventful day for the travelers. (L. Frank Baum, *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*) *[the referenced events occurred after the narrative moment, when the day began]*
>
> For the rest of his career, he **was to brood** on those events. (*Brittanica*, “[English Literature: The Romantic Period](https://www.britannica.com/art/English-literature/The-Romantic-period)”) *[Wordsworth brooded after the narrative moment, when Britain declared war]*

Answer (score 10):

**Only individual words have tense**, not multiword phrases like *was to remember*.

Thus the tense of *was* is the past tense. The construction *be to INFINITIVE* is a periphrastic expression  in English with a particular meaning. In its epistemic mode, it conveys the inevitable future or near present or near future, but not quite so near as *be about to* does. (In its deontic mode, not used here, it’s a light command.) The Spanish did the same.  The OED says of *be* plus an infinitive that it means:

> With infinitive. Expressing an appointed or arranged future action; (hence also) expressing necessity, obligation, duty, fitness, or appropriateness.

So this acts effectively like a modal, and indeed has both an epistemic mode and a deontic mode. Here the epistemic mode is used, the one corresponding to simple *will* rather than to *must*.

To understand what the author was really trying to convey requires looking at the original, not the translation.

> Muchos años después, frente al pelotón de fusilamiento, el coronel Aureliano Buendía **había de recordar** aquella tarde remota en que su padre lo **llevó a conocer** el hielo.

The tense used in the Spanish verb corresponding to the English *was* was the “pretérito imperfecto de indicativo” (*había* rather than *hubo*), a simple tense often just called the “imperfect” in English.

On the other hand, the tense used for the Spanish verb corresponding to the English translation’s *took* was the “pretérito” (*llevó* not *llevaba*), usually called the preterite or simple past indicative in English.

The problem is that unlike Spanish, English does not offer a pair of contrasting morphological (inflectional) past tenses where one past tense has the imperfect aspect and the other past tense has the perfect aspect.

That means there is no easy and direct way to express that distinction in English. You cannot tell just by looking at their inflectional morphology that that *was* had originally been an ongoing / narrative / imperfect tense in Spanish but that that *took* had originally been a completed / perfect / preterite in Spanish.

Another way which the original’s *había de recordar* could have been translated into English is *would remember* rather than *was to remember*. Here *would* serves as the past tense of the modal verb *will* to express the *was going to* type of aspect.

English assembles chained-together sequences of verbs in various inflections to express many nuanced and complex combinations of tense, mode, and aspect. There is almost no end of these, and there’s no reason that each should carry some special name.

> He **would have been going to be hanged** by then, assuming the jury came back the way we expected it to.

There’s no special “name” for that particular periphrastic construction, any more than there is a “name” for the periphrastic  expression *was to remember* in English. But don’t feel bad: *había de recordar* has no name for that construction in Spanish, either. It’s just something you do. It has no name nor needs one.

Same goes for *took to discover* in English, or *llevó a conocer* in Spanish. Those things don’t have their own names; they’re just periphrastic  verbs in the past tense.

Comment: Really? Isn't "was eating" in the present progressive tense, and necessarily has two words? Similarly with "has eaten", and other compound tenses.

Comment: @JamesFennell "Compound tenses" are not morphological tense.

Comment: Thank you! I have no formal training in grammar, so even posing the question I want to ask is tricky for me. I will rephrase the questions.

Comment: @James It depends a bit on whom you ask. Some (even some linguists) use the word _tense_ in a broader sense that encompasses constructions like ‘was eating’, ‘will have been done’, etc. Most linguists nowadays use the term (in reference to English, at least) in a narrower sense, referring only to the morphologically marked forms that directly correspond to temporal aspects, excluding temporal aspects that are expressed through multi-word constructions.

Comment: The most accurate simple translation of "*había de recordar*" would be "*had to remember*": in addition to the distinction between tenses, *haber de* has an element of compulsion which is lost in the quoted translation and in your proposed alternative.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, it wasn't lost: *había de* should almost **never** be translated *had to*. That's because it is the weakest of all ways to express obligation in Spanish. It's so vague as to be epistemic not deontic. It's weaker than *tengo que* or *necesito* or *debo* or even *debería*. The given translation make sense: *was to* is fine here; *had to* would not be. The only *had to* thing that might be weak enough might be *couldn't help but*.